# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

ever since i updated to rails 4 i've been struggeling with strong_params. I finaly tought i had it but now there seems to an unexpected_end some where. i think i overlook everything but it still seems to be wrong somewhere.
i'm very new to ruby on rails aswel.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
#attr_acessor :password
has_secure_password 


before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :nickname,    :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :email,       :presence => true,
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                        :format => { :with => email_regex }
validates :password,    :presence => true,

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @title = "Sign Up"
    @user = User.new
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
end

def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save 
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render "new"
    end
end


private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:nickname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
end
end
```

Comment: this is users_controller not the model :)

Comment: Do you have the error message itself?

Comment: C:/scoreboard test/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Extracted source (around line #5): `code`
3
4
5
6
7
8
          
   def new
    @title = "Sign Up"
    @user = User.new
    end

   def show `code`

Rails.root: C:/scoreboard test/sample_app

Comment: i forgot the comma at the end 

    validates :password,    :presence => true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, i.e., `i forgot the comma at the end validates :password, :presence => true,` OP has resolved the issue. I am just posting it as an answer (not expecting credit for the same) so SO community knows that the question is complete and answered.

You have an extra comma at the end of `validates :password, :presence => true,` which is causing the error.

Removing that would resolve your issue.

```
validates :password, :presence => true
```